# How do I move the + sign to the left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I move the + sign to the left?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

details {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

summary {
  transition: background .75s ease;
  width: 960px;
  outline: 0;
  text-lign: center;
  font-size: 85%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h50 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
}

details p {
  padding: 0 25px 15px 25px;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

summary::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

details[open] summary::after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 90%;
}

details[open] summary:hover {
  background: none;
}

summary:hover {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your html? And maybe use the snippet tool?

Comment: don`t dump all css, add only needed, add your html code also.

Comment: I don't even see what's your problem, you want to move the + sign to the left of what? If it's just slightly to the left of its current position just adjust your `padding-right`in the `summary::after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these following css :

```
 h50{
     padding-left: 35px !important;
    }
summary::after{
    position: absolute;
}
```

will bring + icon on left.

Comment: You think the point is to take the "+" to the left of the text? But in that case use `::before`

Comment: you can update your written css summary::after with summary::before. and add position: absolute; to it. will also work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
summary {
    transition: background .75s ease;
    width: 960px;
    outline: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 85%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

summary::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
details[open] summary::before {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

In the shared code above, you have to remove the `float: right` from the `summary` CSS and remove `justify-content: space-between`, it will work also on using `before` instead of `after`, as `after` is used to insert the element after the text where, as with `before` it will include the element before the text in the summary tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with the accepted answer, using `::after` for something you want on the left is really confusing for anyone reading your code, you have to use `::before` like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

summary {
  transition: background .75s ease;
  width: 960px;
  outline: 0;
  text-lign: center;
  font-size: 85%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h50 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
}

summary::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}


summary:hover {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<summary>
  <h50> Hey </h50>
 </summary>
```